# How to substitue Calibri Regular with Calibri ligth

Tags: fonts

On my system, Calibri Regular shows poorly. It is choppy when the font size < 15pt. Now, I visited many sites and tried many things, changing fonts.conf in the .fontconfig folder, toggling anti-aliasing, I even deleted Calibri.ttf in my ~/.fonts folder.

However, Calibri Light diplays very well!

The question now is: how can I tell my system (Unbuntu Focal 20) to use Calibri Light instead of  Calibri Regular?

Answer (score 2):

Question is a little bit surprising: fonts are set by the user. So set the font to the desired font where you want to change it.

Another issue I should point out is a licensing issue. Unfortunately, the fonts you are using are not free The license of the fonts does not allow you to copy them on a linux system and use them there. Even if they "came for free" with a Windows system for which you have a license to use.

To circumvent legal issues and to hopefully have more success with the display, you could substitute the fonts you are using by free fonts from Google, that have the same font metrics as the ones you use, and are intended as a substitute font for these. It concerns the fonts *Carlito* and *Caladea*. You can install these fonts with the command

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-crosextra-caladea
```

The only reason you sometimes want "compatible" fonts is when user send you documents for collaboration that include proprietary fonts. In any other case, Ubuntu by default comes with several high quality free fonts.